# C++/WinRT: Can I await a single IAsyncAction handle from multiple coroutine calls?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++-winrt

I have coroutine `IAsyncAction Foo`, Which will be called once at the start of my program.

I also have coroutine `IAsyncAction Bar` which will be called multiple times, arbitrarily, and must await for `Foo` at some point.

**Can the multiple calls to `Bar` await for a single call of `Foo` like this?**

`IAsyncAction m_fooAction = Foo();`

(Later, within `Bar`...)

```
co_await m_fooAction;
```

I tried this, but I keep getting an error:
`A delegate was assigned when not allowed` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/hresult-illegal-delegate-assignment).

Please note:
This development is for a Windows 8 Desktop app, so can't use `CoreDispatcher` nor `DispatcherQueue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to C++/WinRT authors, `IAsyncAction` and similar interfaces can only have one awaiter.

As an alternative, they recommend using a kernel handle.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#awaiting-a-kernel-handle

Update:
From Raymond Chen (MSFT):

```
Possible workarounds:

1. Write your own custom object that supports multi-awaiting.
2. Use an existing object that supports multi-awaiting (such as `Concurrency::task`).
3. Use a kernel handle and `resume_on_signal`.

Option 3 is probably simplest.
```

Option 3 worked for my case.